# Trouble modifying a value in a list

Tags: python, list, element, reassign

Using Python 3.11.1 in JupyterLab Version 3.5.2

I,m getting this error message and I'm not sure how. `list` is a list with 6 items within it.  As you can see Dad is the first item.  I am trying to reassign this value to Mike.  The error message is calling this a tuple, but it's a list.

Help Please!

```
list = "Dad", "Bard", "Tammy", "Sean", "Chance", "Gabe"

print(list)

print(list[0])

list[0] = "Mike"
```

('Dad', 'Bard', 'Tammy', 'Sean', 'Chance', 'Gabe')
Dad

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 7
      3 print(list)
      5 print(list[0])
----> 7 list[0] = "Mike"

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

I found multiple examples online that showed the reassignment of a list item, and I duplicated them exactly, but I still got this error message.

Comment: Tuples are immutable; You can only update a value that's inside a list and  you have to define a list with angle brackets []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not creating a list, you're creating a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuples). The syntax for a list uses brackets. A comma-separated "list" (not `list`) of items, without brackets, is a tuple. (It's also not a great idea to use a builtin name as a variable.)

```py
my_list = ["Dad", "Bard", "Tammy", "Sean", "Chance", "Gabe"]
my_list[0] = "Mike"
print(my_list)
```

Comment: Thank you Zac!  Now I see it in my book too.  Wow, it sucks being this green.

Comment: Don't beat yourself up about it, it takes a while to get used to a new language!